# Rails 3 each method and Ajax

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to implement some Ajax in my app. A strange behaviour occurs! 
It's a daycare application. When you show a specific daycare of a specific date you can add some children.
Originally a list of the children of the database is generated and when you click on one of them the page reload and a new child appears in the attendance list of the daycare. It's working fine, i just wanna add some ajax to be more userfriendly !

When you click on child to add him to the daycare, a daycare_item is created ( join table, an id of the child and the id of the daycare ).

I make the changes to make it ajax ready:

- partial for the list
- format.js in the daycare_item controller
- remote true on the link.

It works, no more reload! But the list is updated only when you click a second time on the children list ( the last child added doesn't appears yet ). The js transaction works and if you refresh manually the page, the missing child appears.

I tried few things and here are my results:

In my partial there are

```
<% @daycare.daycare_items.each do |c| %>
  <li><%= c.child.firstname ></li>
<% end %>
```

This produce the "lag" effect with one children who is not showing ( until a full refresh )

But if i put a

```
<%= @daycare.daycare_items.count %>
```

the code is update in time !
I see nothing strange in the logs. 
I'm asking why the .each method make a difference?

Comment: I'm wondering if daycare.daycare_items.count touches or queries the database in such a way that the daycare.daycare_items collection gets refreshed?

Comment: here are the logs after two successives clics in the list : http://pastebin.com/X2ZzY1jC I don't see a query from the count action. And after this action, the count is 2 and there is only on child on the list until i refresh the page then two names are listed. ( the enfant_id is in french, a part of the database is in french i'm on my way to translate few columns asap!). Maybe i have to look closer in the controller or maybe i should play with some locals?

Comment: I don't know if it relates to your problem, but watch for the differences between *.bind* and *.live* (if you're using jQuery off course).

Comment: @Fernando, actually i'm using a simple .html in my create.js.erb for the ajax response.

Comment: I finally find my mistake. A variable was paste during the creation of the partial. This var doesn't depend on the daycare_items controller but on the daycares controller directly.  The var was in the middle of the code and all the code under it stop refreshing. Thats why the .count was working but not the .each ( placed after the bad var ). When the page was manually refreshed the bad var was refreshed too and the mistake was quite invisible to me. I'm editing the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A var was stoping a part of the code to be executed, the var wasn't wrong and doesn't generate an error.

The elements involved: 
daycare_items controller

```
def create
  @daycare = Daycare.find(params[:daycare_id]) # for Ajax
  @daycare_item = DaycareItem.new(params[:daycare_item])
....
end
```

the create.js.erb

```
$('#children-list').html(" <%=j render partial: 'daycares/daycare', locals: { daycare: @daycare } %> ");
```

the view daycares#show

```
<div id="children-list">
  <%= render @daycare %>
</div>
```

the partial ( a part of )  _daycare.html.erb

```
<p>counting test:<%= daycare.daycare_items.count %></p>

# here was something like this <%= @waiting.count %> @waiting is define in the daycare controller but not in the daycare_items controller
<p>
  <% daycare.daycare_items.each do |dci| %>
    <%= dci.enfant.prenom %>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

Comment: Answers should be answers, not a reference to the question. Put the answer in your answer.